# How to catch error when program crash?

Tags: c

How to catch error when program crashes?

Example - Java when crash writes an error log to file.

I writed this code to cause an error:

```
int * invalidPointer = NULL;
printf("%d\n", invalidPointer[0]);
```

And java crashes and saving an error log (hs_error_pid(pid).log) to file, I want to handle an error in program written with C (not in Java, this is only example)

Second example - Chrome when crashes shows information and we can restart browser by clicking yes.

Comment: I think the best solution is to make a code that doesn't crash

Comment: If the program "crashes", it means that it has some unhandled error. If you handle the errors by printing stuff into the log and cleanly exiting the program, it will be the functionality you are seeking.

Comment: In C it's not something portable. When you have a _UB_ anything may happen. It may even work. It may work today and then only on even years. To "catch" an error you have to check error code (if any) of any function you call (also before deferencing any pointer). Java just do it under the hood, C doesn't (speed, speed, speed). You may attach a termination handler (but it's system specific) but...UB doesn't necessarily terminate your program.

Comment: @jigz.- A wise professor told me that if your program doesn't have any bugs, then no one is using your program. The goal is always to write a program with no bugs, but that's not always possible depending on outside influences. So one should always code to handle exceptions to prevent a crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though it is *undefined behavior*, you can use this if you're getting segmentation fault.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Segfault_Handler(int signo)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"\n[!] Oops! Segmentation fault...\n");
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGSEGV,Segfault_Handler);
    return 0;
}
```